# How to get result from third-party api

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios

I want to use a third-party api: [Latin WordNet API](https://latinwordnet.exeter.ac.uk/api), but I meet some problems.

1. The api document shows how to get result by url in browser, but I don't know how to get result by other way.
2. I try to use axios through HTML script element to get the result, like:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#searchBtn')

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://latinwordnet.exeter.ac.uk/api/lemmas/virtus/n/'
    }

    axios(options).then(data => console.log(data))  
})
```

But I get error about CORS. If I use proxy like ngrok, it still doesn't work.

3. I want to try it like normal route, like:

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/api/lemmas/virtus/n/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

I don't know where the result will come from, and I'm also not sure this way is right or false.

Hope anyone may give some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `GET` request:

```
 const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://latinwordnet.exeter.ac.uk/api/lemmas/virtus/n/'
    };

    axios(options)
    .then(response => console.log(response.data.results))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err.response.data));
```

Comment: Sry, this still get error: 
1 .Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://latinwordnet.exeter.ac.uk/api/lemmas/virtus/n/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
2. GET https://latinwordnet.exeter.ac.uk/api/lemmas/virtus/n/ net::ERR_FAILED 200
dictionary.js:11 
3. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: @jadokao cross origin requests are not allowed. try making requests from your server

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to deal with it:

```js
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    axios.get(`https://latinwordnet.exeter.ac.uk/api/lemmas/${req.query.word}/n/`)
         .then(response => {
            return res.json(response.data.results)
         })
})
```

combine route and axios